# Остановка таймера и анимации и переход к следующему циклу

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift3

Здравствуйте! Реализовываю приложение с тренировками. Вообщем добавляю в проект кнопку далее(Перемотка) и появилась проблема, не могу разобраться. Кнопка далее должна срабатывать только при включенном упражнении. При нажатии на далее задумано , что таймер останавливается с анимацией и возвращается в исходное состояние, названия упражнений меняются на следующие по списку. Но у меня получается, что при старте после промотки таймер и анимация одну секунду начинают свое движение и возвращаются в исходное положение, затем вновь начинают свою задачу отсчет и анимацию, но уже полностью дойдя до конца. Не нажимая промотки упражнения начинаются корректно, без возвратов. Кода много поэтому прошу посмотреть кусочек проекта для наглядности, https://yadi.sk/d/ppI7iRCy3EPEEt уже голову сломал... Не обращайте внимание на концовку выполнения тренировки, при тесте проекта в симуляторе... Всем заранее спасибо

Comment: можно по шагам как воспроизвести проблему

Comment: Немного не понял вопроса... Если как увидеть на симуляторе эту проблему, то после нажатия плэй(старт упражнений) начинается первое упражнение, далее нажимая на скип(пропустить) переходим ко второму упражнению. И в этот момент по нажатию на плэй, стартуя второе упражнение, начинается отсчет от пятерки к нулю, и через секунду, вместо того чтоб отобразить четверку, таймер возвращается к пятерке, тоже самое происходит и с анимацией прогресса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

короткий ответ:

в строке 191 во вью контроллере вместо `exersiseTime = 0` написать `exersiseTime = 5`

Длинный ответ:

После нажатия кнопки next вы обнуляете таймер `exersiseTime = 0` и ставите текст в `timerLabel.text` равным пяти. В этом месте у вас вью и модель начинают различаться - на экране вы видите 5, а на самом деле 0. далее, когда вы запускаете упражнение, после первого срабатывания таймера, `exersiseTime` становится = -1 и запускает вашу красивую анимацию возвращения прогресс бара к началу и уже после этого происходит отсчет от 5 к 0.

Как такое дебажить?

Поскольку вы сами сказали, что происходит это, через секунду после начала таймера, то можно поставить брейкпоинт в функции `counting`, которая вызывается каждую секунду и оттуда пойти линия за линией; и сразу обнаружить, что `exersiseTime = -1` и программа сразу заходит в ветку `if exersiseTime == -1 {` и там уже сразу понятно, что после перехода к next таймер не вернули обратно.

Comment: Исправил как сказали, теперь после нажатия next стартует как и должно быть, без возвращений, но пока это упражнение(на которое перепрыгнули) не повторится два раза подряд, оно не заканчивается и не дает его перепрыгнуть

Comment: после нажатия кнопки next вы не увеличиваете индекс текущего упражнения, в просто выводите на экран информацию о следующем упражнении. Т.е. опять выполняется первое упражнение, и только после этого переходит на второе. Это уже второй баг связанный с тем, что вы апдейтите вью и не апдейтите модель.

Comment: в `tappedNext` первой строкой поставить `i += 1` после этого исправить все labels чтоб показывали правильные значения (у вас там есть где то i+2, исправить на i+1)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Теперь все работает корректно!